# CSS Cursor background colour?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a cursor that's a red circle. I was thinking maybe there's a way I could edit a cursor's background colour and then add a border radius to create a circle.

Is this possible?

Note: I do not want to use something like cursor: url(img.jpg), I want to colour the cursor just by css.

Comment: You cant edit browser's default cursor. But you can create a custom cursor   and load that

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/)

Comment: Thank you @dana, I guess Javascript is the only way to go!

Answer (score 1):

If your talking about mouse cursor then currently only thing you can do is 
set

```
cursor: url(...imgpath);
```

Or set it to none then track it with js and use div where you can apply these properties.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to edit a cursor with pure CSS unless you add some javascript into the mix (as seen in the link from @Dana). However you can create an image and set it as a cursor using the `url()` property. SVG images are supported too.